# Issue with permalinks for non-latin characters in the URL

Tags: php, arrays, string, osclass

I am using osclass platform and i 'm trying to convert non-latin characters for categories slugs to latin but i can't make it work. This is what i 've done until now:

Inside the helper file hDefines.php i modified the code like that:

```
function osc_item_url_from_item($item, $locale = '')
{
    if ( osc_rewrite_enabled() ) {
    $url = osc_get_preference('rewrite_item_url');
    if( preg_match('|{CATEGORIES}|', $url) ) {
    $sanitized_categories = array();
    $cat = Category::newInstance()->hierarchy($item['fk_i_category_id']);
            for ($i = (count($cat)); $i > 0; $i--) {
                $sanitized_categories[] = $cat[$i - 1]['s_slug'];
            }

$url = str_replace('{CATEGORIES}', implode("/",
cust_gr_to_latin_cats($sanitized_categories)), $url);


        }
        $url = str_replace('{ITEM_ID}', osc_sanitizeString($item['pk_i_id']), $url);
        $url = str_replace('{ITEM_CITY}', osc_sanitizeString($item['s_city']), $url);

    $url = str_replace('{ITEM_TITLE}', osc_sanitizeString(cust_greek_to_latin($item['s_title'])), $url);


        $url = str_replace('?', '', $url);
        if($locale!='') {
            $path = osc_base_url().$locale."/".$url;
        } else {
            $path = osc_base_url().$url;
        }
    } else {
        $path = osc_item_url_ns($item['pk_i_id'], $locale);
    }
    return $path;
}
```

And in my custom theme functions.php file i added this function:

```
function cust_gr_to_latin_cats($catsgr) {
$grcats  = array('ά','α','Α','Ά','β','Β','γ','Γ','δ','Δ','ε','έ','Ε','Έ','ζ','Ζ','η','ή','Ή','Η','ί','ι','Ί','Ι','κ','Κ','λ','Λ','μ','Μ','ν','Ν','ξ','Ξ','ο','ό','Ό','Ο','π','Π','ρ','Ρ','σ','Σ','ς','τ','Τ','ύ','υ','Υ','Ύ','φ','Φ','χ','Χ','ψ','Ψ','ω','ω','Ω','Ώ','θ','Θ' );
$latr = array('a','a','a','a','v','v','g','g','d','d','e','e','e','e','z','z','h','h','h','h','i','i','i','i','k','k','l','l','m','m','n','n','x','x','o','o','o','o','p','p','r','r','s','s','s','t','t','y','y','y','y','f','f','ch','ch','ps','ps','w','w','w','w','th','th' );

 return str_replace($grcats, $latr, $catsgr); 
}
```

What i am doing wrong ???

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```
function osc_item_url_from_item($item, $locale = '')
{
if ( osc_rewrite_enabled() ) {
$url = osc_get_preference('rewrite_item_url');
if( preg_match('|{CATEGORIES}|', $url) ) {
$sanitized_categories = array();
$cat = Category::newInstance()->hierarchy($item['fk_i_category_id']);
        for ($i = (count($cat)); $i > 0; $i--) {
            $sanitized_categories[] = cust_greek_to_latin($cat[$i - 1]['s_slug']);
        }

$url = str_replace('{CATEGORIES}', implode("/",$sanitized_categories), $url);


    }
    $url = str_replace('{ITEM_ID}', osc_sanitizeString($item['pk_i_id']), $url);
    $url = str_replace('{ITEM_CITY}', osc_sanitizeString($item['s_city']), $url);

$url = str_replace('{ITEM_TITLE}', osc_sanitizeString(cust_greek_to_latin($item['s_title'])), $url);


    $url = str_replace('?', '', $url);
    if($locale!='') {
        $path = osc_base_url().$locale."/".$url;
    } else {
        $path = osc_base_url().$url;
    }
} else {
    $path = osc_item_url_ns($item['pk_i_id'], $locale);
}
return $path;
}
```